# Returning std::function held in a map of std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I have a map of `std::variant` holding several `std::function` specializations, such as:

```cpp
// note the different return types
using function_t = std::variant<std::function<int(void)>, std::function<void(int)>>;
std::map<int, function_t> callbacks;
callbacks[0] = [](){ return 9; };
```

How do I write a `caller(...)` helper function that would give me a reference of the mapped `std::function` held in my variant at an index, allowing a call similar to:

```cpp
int value = caller(callbacks, 0)();
```

A simple visitor doesn't work because of the different return types held in `function_t`, i.e:

```
// cannot compile
auto caller(std::map<int, function_t> callbacks, int idx) {
    return std::visit([](const auto& arg) { return arg; }, callbacks[idx]);    
}
```

Comment: There is no one type which subsumes all of those `std::function` variations. So there's no one possible return type. There is a way to invoke the function stored in the variant given the union of all of the various parameters, but that's different from returning some callable object. Also, how do you plan to call a function that takes an integer without providing an integer parameter?

Comment: @NicolBolas What do you mean there is no type that subsumes all of those **variat**ions?  `function_t` does it.  It is a variant of functions, which subsumes the variants, in this particular case, the **variat**ions of function types....

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: OK, there is no *callable* type that does that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't see why there couldn't be such a type?  I mean, there isn't one in `std` nor is there one in the OP's question.  I mean, use the `overloaded` trick and do `overloaded< std::function<Sig>... >` and you have a type that subsumes all of those variations.  It even throws nicely if it dispatches to the wrong function.  Now, I think using overload resolution here is wrong, hence my answer below doesn't; but extending the answer below to generate a callable type from a variant of functions that throws/returns nullopt on failure isn't tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is being able to call a function only if the arguments match:

```
struct void_t {};

template<class R, class...Args, class...Ts,
  // in C++20 do requires
  std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args)==sizeof...(Ts), bool> = true,
  class R0=std::conditional_t< std::is_same_v<R,void>, void_t, R >
>
std::optional<R0> call_me_maybe( std::function<R(Args...)> const& f, Ts&&...ts ) {

  if constexpr ( (std::is_convertible_v<Ts&&, Args> && ... ))
  {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<R, void>) {
      f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
      return void_t{};
    } else {
      return f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return std::nullopt;
  }
}
template<class R, class...Args, class...Ts,
  // in C++20 do requires
  std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args)!=sizeof...(Ts), bool> = true,
  class R0=std::conditional_t< std::is_same_v<R,void>, void_t, R >
>
constexpr std::optional<R0> call_me_maybe( std::function<R(Args...)> const& f, Ts&&...ts ) {
  return std::nullopt;
}
```

The second part involves some work with variants:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index = {};

template<std::size_t...Is>
using variant_index_t = std::variant< index_t<Is>... >;
template<std::size_t...Is, class R=variant_index_t<Is...>>
constexpr R make_variant_index( std::size_t I, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  constexpr R retvals[] = {
    R( index<Is> )...
  };
  return retvals[I];
}
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto make_variant_index( std::size_t I ) {
  return make_variant_index( I, std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
template<class...Ts>
constexpr auto get_variant_index( std::variant<Ts...> const& v ) {
  return make_variant_index<sizeof...(Ts)>( v.index() );
}
```

That lets you work with variant indexes in a more compile-time friendly way.

```
template<class...Ts>
std::optional<std::variant<Ts...>> var_opt_flip( std::variant<std::optional<Ts>...> const& var ) {
  return std::visit( [&](auto I)->std::optional<std::variant<Ts...>> {
    if (std::get<I>(var))
      return std::variant<Ts...>(std::in_place_index_t<I>{}, *std::get<I>(var));
    else
      return std::nullopt;
  }, get_variant_index(var) );
}
```

this lets us take a `variant<optional<Ts>...>` and produce an `optional<variant<Ts...>>`, even if there are duplicate types.

We now need to be able to build the right return value.

Now we can write this, a function that takes a variant of functions and arguments, and maybe calls the active one:

```
template<class...Sigs, class...Ts>
auto call_maybe( std::variant<std::function<Sigs>...> const& vf, Ts&&...ts )
{
  using R0 = std::variant< decltype(call_me_maybe(std::function<Sigs>{}, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...))... >;
  R0 retval = std::visit(
    [&](auto I)->R0 {
      return R0( std::in_place_index_t<I>{}, call_me_maybe(std::get<I>(vf), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... ) );
    },
    get_variant_index(vf)
  );
  return var_opt_flip( std::move(retval) );
}
```

Then we rewrite `caller` to use it:

```
using function_t = std::variant< std::function< void() >, std::function< int(int) > >;

template<class...Ts>
auto caller(std::map<int, function_t> const& callbacks, int idx, Ts&&...ts) {
  auto it = callbacks.find(idx);
  using R = decltype(call_maybe( it->second, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... ));
  // wrong index:
  if (it == callbacks.end())
    return R(std::nullopt);
  // ok, give it a try:
  return call_maybe( it->second, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}
```

There are going to be some compilers who don't like what I did with `auto I`; on those, `decltype(I)::value` replacing `I` might help (what can I say, not all compilers are C++ compliant).

The basic idea is that we create a variant, with matching indexes, of the possible return values of the functions.  We then return an optional one of those, to deal with the fact that failure is definitely a possibility (at runtime).

`call_me_maybe` is (beyond a song reference) a way to be able to pretend we can call anything.  That is where a `nothing_t` might be useful when `R` is `void`.

The `variant_index_t` is a trick I use to deal with variants as generic sum types with possibly repeat types in it.

First we define a compile time integer called an `index`.  It is based off of the existing `std::integral_constant`.

Then we make a variant of these, such that alternative 3 is the compile-time index 3.

We can then use `std::visit( [&](auto I){/*...*/}, get_variant_index(var) )` to work with the index of a variant as a compile time constant.

If `var` has 4 alternatives and holds alternative 2, then `get_variant_index` returns a `std::variant<index<0>, index<1>, index<2>, index<3>>` that has `index<2>` populated in it.

(At runtime this is plausibly going to be represented by a 64 bit integer `2`.  I find this funny.)

When we `std::visit` this `variant_index`, the lambda we pass **gets passed the `index_t<I>`**.  So the lambda has a compile time constant passed to it.  In a compiler that isn't dumb, you can `constexpr` extract the value from the `index_t<I>` by the `operator std::size_t` it has implicitly.  For dumb compilers, you have to do `std::decay_t<decltype(I)>::value`, which will be the same compile-time integer.

Using **that** compile-time integer we can `std::get<I>(var)` the value inside the lambda (and guarantee the one at the right spot) and we can use it to construct **another** variant at the same alternative, even if that other variant has ambiguous alternatives.  In your case, you'd see that if you had

```
std::function<int(int)>
std::function<int(int,int)>
```

the "variant of results" looks like `std::variant<int,int>` -- which is different from a `std::variant<int>`.

(As an additional step, you could remove duplicate types from this variant, but I'd advise doing that separately)

Each of the `call_me_maybe` calls returns an `optional<R>`.  But a `variant<optional<R>...>` is **dumb**, so I flip it to a `optional<variant<R>...>`.

Which means you can quickly check if the function call worked, and if it does you can see what value you got out of it.

---

Test code:

```
    std::map<int, function_t> callbacks = {
        { 0, []{ std::cout << 0 << "\n"; } },
        { 1, [](int x){ std::cout << "1:" << x << "\n"; return x+1; } },
    };
    std::optional<std::variant<void_t, int>> results[] = {
        caller(callbacks, 0),
        caller(callbacks, 0, 1),
        caller(callbacks, 1),
        caller(callbacks, 1, 1),
    };
    for (auto&& op:results) {
        std::cout << (bool)op;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    auto printer = [](auto val) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(val), void_t>) {
            std::cout << "void_t";
        } else {
            std::cout << val;
        }
    };
    int count = 0;
    for (auto&& op:results) {
        
        std::cout << count << ":";
        if (!op) {
            std::cout << "nullopt\n";
        } else {
            std::visit( printer, *op );
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        ++count;
    }
```

I get this output:

> ```
> 0
> 1:1
> 1001
> 0:void_t
> 1:nullopt
> 2:nullopt
> 3:2
> ```

The first two lines are the `void()` and `int(int)` `std::function`s logging their call.

The third line shows which calls succeeded -- the 0 argument call to `void()` and the 1 argument call to `int(int)`.

The last 4 lines are the results stored.  The first one, the `optional<variant>` is engaged and holds a `void_t`.  The 2nd and 3rd call failed so `nullopt`, and the last one contains the result of passing `1` to the function that returns `1+1`.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/558a6904dca20acc).

From the return value, you can see if the call worked (see if the outer optional is engaged), determine which callback was called if one was (the variant index), and get the value of the called variant (do a visit on it).

---

If the number of function types is large, there is an optimization you should consider.

The above has two nested `std::visits` of a variant index, both guaranteed to return the same value.  This means O(n^2) code is being generated where only O(n) is required, where n is the number of alternatives in `function_t`.

You can clean that up by passing the variant index "down" to `call_maybe` and `var_opt_flip` as an extra argument.  In theory a compiler could work out that the other n^2-n generated code elements are unreachable, but that both requires a lot of work on the part of the compiler and would be fragile even if it worked.

Doing so will reduce build times (and this kind of tomfoolery can cost build times; don't call this in a commonly included public header!), and could reduce runtime executable size.

Most programming languages and most uses of C++ don't permit O(n) code to generate more than O(n) binary; but templates are powerful enough, and std variant in particular, to generate O(n^2) and even O(n^3) binary code output.  So some care should be taken.

Comment: Map `void` to `nullptr`, always return straight `std::nullopt` if not callable, and you get something simpler and more general for the first part: `<class... Ts>
auto try_call(Ts&&... ts)
noexcept(!std::is_invocable_v<Ts...> || std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<Ts...>)
{
 if constexpr (!std::is_invocable_v<Ts...>)
  return std::nullopt;
 else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, std::invoke_result_t<Ts...>>)
  return std::invoke(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...), std::optional(nullptr);
 else
  return std::optional(std::invoke(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...));
}`

Comment: This is insane. Thank you for your time, effort, and thoroughness.

Comment: I knew there was no easy solution to my question, but the amount of fluentness and time you need to write this is is in a different ballpark. I ended up with something much less generic but maintenable, which makes me wonder - would you allow such code in your team's codebase?

Comment: @Fluffy No, I wouldn't allow a map to a variant of functions in my codebase.  :)  Type safety is too useful to throw out that way, even if I could wrap it up into an abomination like the above and make it technically type safe.  If I had to use an abomination like the above, I hope (a) I'd have more time to polish it, and (b) I would rework the requirements to make it less of an abomination.  One thing that would be key would be looking into Haskell and similar languages, where this kind of code is more natural, to make the C++ code better.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont To be honest I got rid of it all myself, there was no need of an heterogeneous map in the first place, laying everything down made that pretty much clear. The design is flawed, so is the code. Now I just need to find a way of *not* thinking those ideas through over and over again. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @Fluffy Good!  I enjoy solving problems where the other answers are "it cannot be done", but it doesn't mean it *should* be done!  As for the code, the variant index thing is quite useful if you are doing anything non-trivial with variants (if a bit weird).  The `call_me_maybe` is a bit stupid, because you should generally know if you can call a function (why are you trying to call a function with the wrong number of arguments or types?)  The rest of it is scaffolding to allow for that strange map.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Basically I got objects dynamically registering functions at run-time, making them available only if some criteria are met. So we might have user-code calling a function that can't be called. This all stemmed from wanting to write sth like `map_of_features[feature_id](args...)`.

Comment: @Fluffy *nod*, but the args for a given feature are going to be known both at registration and at call time.  Variants are only really useful if they are going to be used uniformly in a non-trivial way.  I'd argue for a variant of maps here, not a map to variants.  If people really want to say `run_feature[feature_id](args...)` I'd name the feature-ids with types that know which arguments they take.  Unless you are in a strange situation, where a user specifies *both* the feature-id by number *and* the *types* of the arguments package to send by some way, that will work better.

Comment: Something like `try_call()` can be useful in generic code, if you don't know whether a hook exists or not for any specific type. It allows you to keep the details confined to a single small spot. Though using `std::is_invocable()` and `if constexpr` directly is more flexible.

Comment: @Deduplicator I can't think of one where try call is a better idea than is invocable and if constexpr, but I could believe one exists.